# javascript not reading entered value in input box

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am unable to get the function AreaT() to verify and validate the entered value in the input box as the answer to the area of a triangle.
I keep getting "wrong" message even for the correct answer.
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for taking the time to check my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

var height = Math.floor(Math.random()*20 +1);

var base = Math.floor(Math.random()*30 +2);
var area = getElementById("area");

 function AreaT(){

 document.getElementById('height').value = height;
    document.getElementById('base').value = base;
if(area== 1/2 * base * height){
document.write("correct")
}
else{
document.write("wrong");
}
}
</script>

  </head>
  <body>
 <form>
<h2>HEIGHT:</h2><input  type="button" size="20" id="height"/>
<h2>BASE: </h2><input  type="button" size="20" id="base"/>
<h2>AREA: </h2>Enter The Area here:<input  type="text" size="20"  id="area"/>

 <input  type="button" size="20" value = "Calculate" onClick ="AreaT()"/>
</form>



</body>


</html>
```

Comment: It's `document.getElementById("area")` not `getElementById("area")` and it should be called after the element exists on the page. As you have it, it's undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

HTML

```
<body>
<h2>HEIGHT:</h2><input  type="button" size="20" id="height"/>
<h2>BASE: </h2><input  type="button" size="20" id="base"/>
<h2>AREA: </h2>Enter The Area here:<input  type="number" size="20"  id="area"/>

<input  type="button" size="20" value = "Calculate" onClick ="AreaT()"/>
</body>
```

Javascript (put in `<header>` tag)

```
var height = Math.floor(Math.random()*20 +1);
var base = Math.floor(Math.random()*30 +2);

document.getElementById('height').value = height;
document.getElementById('base').value = base;



 function AreaT(){
var area = document.getElementById("area").value;
if(area == 1/2 * base * height){
document.write("correct")
}
else{
document.write("wrong");
}
}
```

Adding on to what was already mentioned, you need to add a `.value` to the area element as well. I also changed the input type of AREA to `number`.

Comment: Thank you JL.thanks for taking the time to fix my code. It works now.

Comment: @user3308574 Just a reminder, you can click the checkmark on this answer to mark your question as resolved!

Answer (score 1):

Change `getElementById("area")` to `document.getElementById("area").value`. You also need to assign `area` from inside your `AreaT()` function, otherwise it's not gonna get the value that the user typed in.

Also, your javascript needs to be below those form elements, otherwise it can't "see" them and you will get undefined values.

Comment: Thank you ElGavilan. You are right. I placed the javascript below and along with the advice of JL above the whole code works nicely.